# can i charge my 20v 3.25 amp directly from a 24v battery

Tags: laptop, battery, power

I want to know if i can charge me laptop directly from a 24v solar battery using the connector to the laptop eliminating the ac transformer. 
The laptop transformer DC output is 20v 3.25 amp. does 4 volts make a difference?

Comment: The extra 4v does place an additional burden on the power circuits.  You should just buy a Potentiometer and use a volt meter to adjust it to the right output voltages.  Probably cost lest than $2 and save the power supply circuits.

Comment: *"The laptop transformer DC output is 20v..."* -- Transformers to not output DC voltages.  The PSU is more than just a transformer.  That 4 volts is significant; it's 20% more voltage than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I woudln't recommend it.

First, what is the current rating of the solar power source? The laptop power supply is 20 V × 3.25 Amps = so it is capable of 65 W of power. Anything less and you probably won’t charge the laptop, or charge it very very slowly if at all.

Second, a lot of the protection for the laptop is in that power supply:  protection from surges, voltage spikes, etc... connecting it directly to a 24 V battery removes those protections.

Third, that 20 V is very specific. Pushing 24 V into your laptop unregulated may burn something.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Some thoughts: 1) In these solar powered setups, solar panels recharge the battery but you operate from battery power. The 3.25 A doesn't sound excessive for the batteries typically used, but it would be good to be cognizant of how much run time there is.  There's no built-in way to query battery charge, so a voltmeter or something would be needed to avoid power loss if the battery runs down.   2) Re: protection from surges and spikes, operating from the battery is the best protection from those. It's like running from a UPS. That point kind of detracts from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. I have attempted it unsuccessfully. My 24v battery bank gets as high as 29v during mid day, and this is much too high for the laptop. When I remove the AC-DC transformer from the laptop PSU, and plug it into the computer, nothing occurs. I just bought a DC-DC step down module that I will use to bring the voltage down to 19.5v and then try again. I'm honestly not very hopeful at this point though.

Using a laptop car charging adapter, on a 12v battery, or using an inverter with the original charger, this works fine.